# How can I profile a complete C++ build?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, profiling, build-process

I'm developing an application in C++ on Windows XP, using Eclipse as my IDE, and a Makefile-based build system (with custom tools to generate the Makefiles). In addition, I'm using LZZ, which allows me to write a single file, which then gets split into a header and an implementation file. I'm using TDM's port of GCC 4.

What tools or techniques could I use to determine exactly how much time each part of the build process takes, and why it is slow?

Of particular interest would be:

- How much time does make need to figure out to parse the Makefiles, figure out the dependencies, check the timestamps, etc?
- How much time does Eclipse need before and after the build?
- How much time does GCC spend on parsing system and boost headers?

**P.S.:** This is my home project, so expensive tools are out of reach for me, but could be documented here anyway if they are particularly relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Make and GCC are very verbose about what they're doing, a very crude way to get a high-level overview of time spent is to pipe make's output through a script that timestamps each line:

```
make | perl -MTime::HiRes -pe "printf '%.5f ', Time::HiRes::time()"
```

(I'm using [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) to do this, but from what I gather, [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) may now be the recommended Perl version for Windows.)

Reformat or process the timestamps to your liking.

To get more details about GCC in particular, use the `--time-report` option.

To find out how much overhead Eclipse adds, use a stopwatch to time builds from Eclipse and from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using boost, most likely most of time is spent in template instantiation and subsequent optimization. You can tell GCC to report time spent, `-time-report` (UNIX option, might be something else on Windows GCC)

and if you are trying to speed up your compilation time, disable optimization, `-O0` (last letter is number zero, first letter is capital o)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SparkBuild](http://www.sparkbuild.com), a free gmake/nmake replacement that can generate an annotated build log with precise timing information for every job in the build.  You can load that file into SparkBuild Insight to get a graphical overview of where the time goes.

See [this blog](http://www.sparkbuild.com/profiles/blogs/build-profiling-with) for an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of GNU make called [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) that provides profiling information.